# Overriding Bootstrap 3's Focus

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to override the focus attribute for Bootstrap 3's a:focus class.  This is one of only a couple classes that I'm trying to edit, so I'm not really interested in rebuilding the entire project.  That being said, overriding this particular style has been problematic.

I've loaded my two stylesheets as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
```

and have overloaded Boostrap's class (in app.css) with:

```
a:focus {
  outine: 0 !important;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Weirdly enough, no matter why I try, the outline object never gets loaded into my web browser.  As you can see from my firebug screenshot, it's totally ignoring that line.  The weirdest part is, if I type the above override directly into firebug, it works.  So I'm not sure what to make of that.

screenshot of firebug's view of app.css:

[image: missing line]

I've tried replacing `0 !important` with `none`, `none none`, and `none !important`, but nothing seems to have solved it.

Comment: If you are adding a line of code, and not overriding; add it to bootstrap.css?

Comment: @JordanD I am not adding the line.  Both of those lines exist in the bootstrap code.  They need to be overridden by the app.css file.  I really don't want the headache of trying to maintain editing the bootstrap file (and its min) across upgrades.

Comment: Well if it is part of bootstrap.css, and you included the bootstrap.css file correctly, it should appear?

Comment: @JordanD Yes it should, the screenshot is of app.css.  Which is dropping one of the overrides.

Comment: You name it `outine` and not `outline`. And `outine` is not a valide css attribute so it does not appear in the inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple a typo: you've used `outine` instead of `outline`.

```
a:focus {
  outine: 0 !important;
```